# Filter data based on macro variable values in SAS

Tags: macros, sas

```
%let var_list = n1 n2 n3;

data A;
call streaminit(123);       /* set random number seed */
do i = 1 to 100;
   n1 = rand("Normal");
   n2 = rand("Normal");
   n3 = rand("Normal");
   output;
end;
run;
```

Suppose I want to filter a data set based on marco variable "&var_list", filtering all the data where each value in the macro variable is greater than 0.
How should I write the macro？

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 'Each value in the macro variable is greater than 0', do you mean each variable in the data set is greater than 0? Your macro variables are characters. Why do you want a macro? An array is a better approach and what do you want as output. What if N1<0 but N2>0, is that record removed?

Comment: Goodness, I miss the days of `marco`.  Can you restate the question using actual values, show a dataset **have** and then what you **want**.  Then show what non-macro plain SAS code you have used or tried to get from have to want.  Only at that point would talking about marco be realistic or silly.

Comment: Did you mean you want to find records where N1, N2 and N3 are all positive?  `if n(of n1 n2 n3)=3 and min(of n1 n2 n3)>0;`

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean you want to find records where N1, N2 and N3 are all positive?

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  if nmiss(of n1 n2 n3)=0 and min(of n1 n2 n3)>0; 
run;
```

Converting to use a macro variable.

```
%let varlist=n1 n2 n3;
data want ;
  set have ;
  if nmiss(of &varlist)=0 and min(of &varlist)>0; 
run;
```